# Bouncy Castle and TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM

Tags: java, security, tls1.2, bouncycastle

One of my test tools(I only have the binary), uses java for TLS communication.
Since standard java does not provide support, Bouncy Castle is used for ciphers that use CCM.
After configuring Bouncy Castle, my tool works for majority of CCM related ciphers (Eg:
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM).
However, the tool fails for TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM cipher suite.

Below is the error trace:

```
14:34:15.350 INFO  - Start TCP Listener on 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10075 14:34:23.818 INFO  - Accept connection Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=53357,localport=10075] 14:34:23.831 DEBUG
- /127.0.0.1:10075<-/127.0.0.1:53357(1): enter state: Sta2 - Transport connection open May 02, 2022 2:34:23 PM org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTlsServer notifyAlertRaised INFO: Server raised fatal(2) handshake_failure(40) alert: Failed to read record org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: handshake_failure(40); No selectable cipher suite
        at org.bouncycastle.tls.AbstractTlsServer.getSelectedCipherSuite(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTlsServer.getSelectedCipherSuite(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsServerProtocol.generateServerHello(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsServerProtocol.handleHandshakeMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.processHandshakeQueue(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.processRecord(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadRecord(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.blockForHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsServerProtocol.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.handshakeIfNecessary(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect$AppDataInput.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.dcm4che3.util.StreamUtils.readAvailable(StreamUtils.java:57)
        at org.dcm4che3.util.StreamUtils.readFully(StreamUtils.java:68)
        at org.dcm4che3.net.PDUDecoder.readFully(PDUDecoder.java:225)
        at org.dcm4che3.net.PDUDecoder.nextPDU(PDUDecoder.java:159)
        at org.dcm4che3.net.Association$2.run(Association.java:571)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

14:34:23.918 INFO  - /127.0.0.1:10075<-/127.0.0.1:53357(1): i/o exception: org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: handshake_failure(40); No selectable cipher suite in State: Sta2 - Transport connection open
```

Any pointers to why it fails for this cipher whereas TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM works?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are configuring only that suite (or the tool(?) is) whatever client is trying to connect to you isn't offering it therefore the handshake fails. If you are configuring multiple suites, the client isn't offering _any_ of them (or for EC is offering the suite(s) but not with acceptable curve(s)). BCTLS doesn't have full logging of the handshake like SunJSSE does, so try to either get a trace at the client or get a network-level trace with something like wireshark or tcpdump, and look at the ClientHello message to see what is offered and what is not.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 At server side, I have configured only TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM. I checked the ClientHello message with WireShark and it displays Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM (0xc09c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from BouncyCastle github forum, I have found the solution for the issue.
It required 2 additional steps to be performed:

1. Copy bcpkix-$version.jar to %JAVA_HOME%\lib\ext path
2. Update ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm=PKIX in java.security file